VS Code first opens the integrated terminal, then turns into external terminal
My VS Code opens the integrated terminal on the last 1~2 second, and then it turns into an external terminal. No idea why.
I try to trun off the ConPTY  in VScode, as suggested in the following post but it doesn't help: How do I get around the verified bug in Windows 1903 and launch the VSCode integrated terminal?

There are many other suggestions in that linked answer besides turn off the ConPTY in VSCode. Did you try them?

I did try some options but none of them resolve it... However, a few days afterward, VScode just fix it by itself... I don't know if it is fixed by a hotfix or what (Previously, restarting didn't work)
